# Zermelo's or Fraenkel's early consideration of something equivalent to countable Replacement

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, set-theory

I have now claimed a few times on the internet, based on something (sensible!) I read, that at some point in the 1920s, that Zermelo at one point considered as a set theoretic axiom (schema) something equivalent to a restricted version of Replacement, corresponding to a function with countable domain, before going all out by 1930. Now, however, I cannot find the document in which I read this, and I cannot remember anything else about it! I foolishly didn't write this down. I have consulted [Ebbinghaus' book](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-49553-6), and I can't see it in there. I have consulted Kanamori's edition of [Zermelo's collected works](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-79384-7), and I can't see it in the prefatory essays on Zermelo's 1929 or 1930 set theory papers.

However, and this is where my faulty memory shows up even more: I also in one place claimed it was *Fraenkel* who considered countable Replacement! I cannot find this either. And in trying to hunt down my original source, I recognised the phrase

> it is also to be noted that Skolem only wrote that "we could introduce" Replacement

in Kanamori's 2012 *[In Praise of Replacement](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41472440)*. But I didn't see, on a search through there, anything corresponding to my half-remembered claim.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Given that your preliminary research has yielded no leads, I would expect this to turn into a challenging quest. Is there any contextual information that might help us? For example, did you come across this information in a blog, a journal, a book? Did you hear about it from a colleague (at a particular conference perhaps, or at a particular institution)? Were you researching a particular topic when you encountered this information? Based on personal experience: False memories are a thing; they can be re-enforced by repeated telling. How confident are you (percentage) about the Zermelo origin?

Comment: It was in a book, I'm pretty sure. I was looking into the history of Replacement and/or the cumulative hierarchy, as I believe I was looking into Borel Determinacy at the time. It's not so much as it's a false memory: I wrote comments online at the time pointing out this interesting fact I'd just read. So either I or the author made a slip, or this is out there somewhere.

Comment: That is helpful context. Could the following be related? G. Kreisel, "Logical Aspects of the Axiomatic Method: On Their Significance in (Traditional) Foundations and in Some (Now) Common or Garden Varieties of Mathematics", In: H.-D. Ebbinghaus, et al. (eds.), *Logic Colloquium '87*, (Granada, Spain, July 1987), Elsevier 1989, pp. 183-217. On p. 213: " *The second example concerns (the power set operation, and) the replacement axiom, which Zermelo  omitted in 1908, or, more specifically, transfinite recursion, which Fraenkel and von Neumann considered in the twenties, and Borel determinacy.* "

Comment: Also, at the point in time that I was reading this (July last year), I wrote: "Fraenkel, after the work where he (apparently tentatively!) suggested Replacement as a strengthening of Zermelo’s axioms, also proposed an alternative axiom equivalent to countable Replacement." So perhaps this is his 1925 paper? My mathematical German is far too weak to skim these papers and look for key words.

Comment: Matthew Foreman and Akihiro Kanamori (eds.), "Handbook of Set Theory, Vol. 2", Springer 2010. Page 12: " *In the 1920s, fresh initiatives in axiomatics structured the loose Zermelian framework with new features and corresponding axioms, the most
consequential moves made by John von Neumann [...] in his doctoral work [...] Fraenkel and [...] Skolem had independently proposed Replacement 
to ensure that a specific collection resulting from a simple recursion be a set, but it was von Neumann's formal incorporation of transfinite recursion as method which brought Replacement into set theory.* "

Comment: I can read German, but I would need a pointer to "his 1925 paper". I found: A. Fraenkel, "Zehn Vorlesungen über die Grundlagen der Mengenlehre" (Ten lectures on the foundations of set theory), Kiel, Germany, June 8-12 1925; Springer 1927.

Comment: I don't have access to the full text of Fraenkels *Vorlesungen*, but I do see from the table of contents that he briefly talked about Replacement ("Das Axiom der Ersetzung", p. 114).

Comment: Re "1925 paper". If this refers to the following, I do not have access to it: A. Fraenkel, "Untersuchungen über die Grundlagen der Mengenlehre." *Mathematische Zeitschrift* **22**, 250–273 (1925).

Comment: That paper can be accessed here: https://eudml.org/doc/167842

Comment: Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus, *Ernst Zermelo, 2n ed.*, 2015, appears to trace the genesis of Replacement in detail in section 3.5: "The Fraenkel Correspondence of 1921 and the Axiom of Replacement".

Comment: Thanks. I had searched at the Goettingen Digitization Center, but apparently didn't do it properly. I have perused the paper, and while I am out of my mathematical depth here it seems the major contribution of the paper is a *refinement* of "Axiom der Aussonderung" (axiom of separation; axiom V in the paper). In the introduction, Fraenkel acknowledges von Neumann's different approach to extending Zermelo's system of axioms (also briefly referenced in section 28.), and points to material yet to be published, so it seems like things were very much in flux at the time of writing.

Comment: Michael Hallett's *Cantorian Set Theory and Limitation of Size* (1984), pages 282-6 and 296-7, discusses a restricted version of Replacement considered by Fraenkel in 1922-6. But I'm not at all sure that this is related to your question.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley that's a good find, and  very interesting, but somewhat orthogonal to the question, as you suggested.